# if+or fails even though inverse condition works

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm teaching myself python and I am trying to understand why the below example fails.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
vWHEN = sys.argv[1]
print (vWHEN)
if vWHEN != "before" or vWHEN != "after":
 exit("ERROR: " + vWHEN + " is invalid. Should be: 'before' or 'after'")
```

The output is as follows:

```
$ ptest.py before
before
ERROR: before is invalid. Should be: 'before' or 'after'
```

But the following *does* work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4
vWHEN = sys.argv[1]
if vWHEN == "before" or vWHEN == "after":
 print (vWHEN)
else:
 exit("ERROR: " + vWHEN + " is invalid. Should be: 'before' or 'after'")
```

Output:

```
$ ptest.py before
before
```

Comment: `if vWHEN != "before" or vWHEN != "after"` The variable will _always_ be unequal to at least one of those values, so this `if` statement will _always_ be true.

Comment: Because `vWHEN != "after"` is True...

Comment: No matter what `vWHEN` is, it can't be both `"before"` and `"after"`, so the test for the `if` will always be true.

Comment: `if vWHEN in {"before", "after"}` could be clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with a logic error. Let's start with the current version (2nd):

```
if a == "before" or a == "after":
```

This reads like English, the condition is valid if `a` is either `"before"` or `"after"`. However, your first (incorrect) version is:

```
if a != "before" or a != "after":
```

This will always be `True` since `a` cannot have 2 values so one of the branches of `or` will always be `True`.

---

**Solution**:

Let's apply [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to see how to invert the conditional logic. To represent the inverse logic of your correct case, which was

```
A or B
```

we need

```
not (A or B)
```

which according to the laws is

```
(not A) and (not B)
```

Therefore, the correct version for your first `if` statement should be:

```
if a != "before" and a != "after":  # notice the and instead of the or
```

---

**Side Note**: to simplify testing against multiple values, try using the following approach:

```
if a in ("before", "after"):
```

or

```
if a not in ("before", "after"):
```

It reads much easier thus also being easier to reason with

Comment: Ok, now i'm a little embarrassed. This is blatantly obvious. I need 'and' not 'or'. Making that change made it work. I've been looking at code for a few hours now, think I need a snack break ;)

Comment: @spezticle it happens. as you said, really helps to take a break

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want to change your logic to be

```py
if vWHEN != "before" and vWHEN != "after":
 exit("ERROR: " + vWHEN + " is invalid. Should be: 'before' or 'after'")
```

When you use `or` instead of `and`, no matter what the value of `vWHEN`is it will always enter the `if` body.

Answer (score 2):

`vWHEN != "before" or vWHEN != "after"` will always be true. Any string is either not equal to "before" or to "after" (e.g., "before" is not equal to "after").

You should use the **and** boolean operator - only if the user inputs neither "before" nor "after" do you need to error out:

```
if vWHEN != "before" and vWHEN != "after":
    # Here ----------^
```